# Bash - broken symlinks

Tags: linux, bash, unix, debian, symlink

I'm having troubles with writing bash script under Debian. I have folder which contains some more folders and files (It's a tree of folders). This tree contains symlinks. I want to go recursively through whole structure, detect broken symlinks a print them (not their target, but the links itself) in this fasion (absolute paths):

```
/tmp/Foo/Bar/symlink1
/tmp/Foo/symlink2
/tmp/Foo/Goo/symlink3
```

But I do not want and can't use classic

```
find -L $(path) -type l
```

Because this follows the correct links out of given structure and detects broken links outside of structure and I don't want these in my printout since I want only detect broken symlinks inside of my structure that is given in $(path) and all of it subdirectories. Could you please help me out? I have feeling that this will require some black magic with readlink and some loop, but I have no idea how. Thanks for advice! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `-F`. What does it do?

Comment: find -F $(path) -type l => Follows the symlink (dereferences symlink and replaces with referenced file or directory) and when it cannot be followed -type l is executed and tests if file is symlink. If is, the it's printed out.

Comment: Which variant or version of `find` supports `-F`?

Comment: Ohhhh I'm sorry.... I mean -L, God damn, I'm really tired... -L ... I mean find -L

Comment: Apart from all the hassle, the next variable after `Foo` and `Bar` should be `Baz` and not `Goo`. :-)

Comment: If the time taken by following the symlinks out of the tree isn't problematic then would it not suffice to just use something like `linkfind() { find -L "$1" -type -l | grep -v "^$1"; }`? If that doesn't work then the best solution I can think of is to find the symlinks in the first pass and pass them all to a second find something like `find -L -maxdepth 1 "${paths[@]}" -type l` (assuming that, untested, idea works).

Answer (score 0):

The following command will do the job without following symlinks:

```
find /tmp/ -type l -printf '%p|' -exec stat -L {} \; 2>&1 | grep 'No such' | cut -d'|' -f1
```

The `-L` option of `stat` follows the link by checking the file behind it (do not confuse it with `-L` option of `find` however). When the link is not found, you get error:

```
stat: cannot stat `./symlink': No such file or directory
```

However, we want to print the name of the file as well, so that's why we use `-printf '%p|'`. The pipe here is used just as a delimiter (I doubt that you have files with pipe in their name), to separate the file name from the `stat` error that would be printed otherwise.